# JMeter failed to keep JSON order by using fastjson JSONObject.parseObject

Tags: json, jmeter, fastjson

**Backgroud:**

In Jmeter, I need to get the json post data, and then parse to the JSONObject

But the key order should the same

The json post data is: { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3", "four": "4" }

After JSON Object parse, it also should be: { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3", "four": "4" }

**Solution:**

In pure java, I could use the following code to keep the order

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.Feature;

String requestBody = "{ \"one\": \"1\", \"two\": \"2\", \"three\": \"3\", \"four\": \"4\" }";
log.info("********************requestBody: " + requestBody);

// Expected: keep the JSONObject key oder same as the body data
// But following code not working in JMeter JSR223 Sampler, it works fine in pure JAVA
JSONObject maps = JSONObject.parseObject(requestBody, Feature.OrderedField);
log.info("********************maps expected: " + maps);
```

**Issue:**

But the above code is not working in JMETER JSR223 Sampler, I get the following error:

```
Static method parseObject( java.lang.String, com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.Feature ) not found in class'com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject'...
```

**Reproduce:**

Save the following code as .jmx file to reproduce in JMeter

You need to download the fastjson 1.2.83, and put to the jmeter lib folder: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson/1.2.83

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.5">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="JSON Sort Issue" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">{&#xd;
  &quot;one&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,&#xd;
  &quot;two&quot;: &quot;2&quot;,&#xd;
  &quot;three&quot;: &quot;3&quot;,&#xd;
  &quot;four&quot;: &quot;4&quot;&#xd;
}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">httpbin.org</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/post</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <JSR223PreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223PreProcessor" testname="JSR223 预处理程序" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="script">import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.Feature;

String requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
log.info(&quot;********************requestBody: &quot; + requestBody);

// UnExpected: key order is not same as the body data
JSONObject maps = JSONObject.parseObject(requestBody);
log.info(&quot;********************maps unexpected: &quot; + maps);

// Expected: keep the JSONObject key oder same as the body data
// But following code not working in JMeter JSR223 Sampler, it works fine in pure JAVA
JSONObject maps = JSONObject.parseObject(requestBody, Feature.OrderedField);
log.info(&quot;********************maps expected: &quot; + maps);
</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">beanshell</stringProp>
          </JSR223PreProcessor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you declare your `maps` variable twice in the same scope, this is not valid code at all.

Coming back to your question: just change language to `groovy`, it will resolve your issue.

[image]

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy performance is much better comparing the other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter). Moreover Groovy supports Java better and Beanshell doesn't support any Java 5+ feature.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help, with groovy, it is working now!!!!